# how to make two or more combinations of specific letter?

Tags: python, list, iterator, combinations, python-itertools

I am novice to python and I was struggling to do this for last one week could someone help me out of this problem which would be very helpful to finish my project.

I tried to do single mutation and their 2,3 combinations based on the user input for given sequence:

INPUT SEQUENCE:                                                                                                        >PEACCEL

USER MUTATION INPUT FILE:
   E2R
   C4W
   E6G

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import getopt
import sys
import itertools as it 
from itertools import groupby

def main(argv):
try:
    opts,operands = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'i:m:o:'["INPUT_FILE:=","MUTATIONFILE:=","OUTPUT_FILE:=","help"])
    if len(opts) == 0:
        print "Please use the correct arguments, for usage type --help "
    else:
        for option,value in opts:
            if option == "-i" or option == "--INPUT_FILE:":
                seq=inputFile(value)
            if option == "-m" or option == "--MUTATION_FILE:":
                conA=MutationFile(value)
            if option == "-o" or option == "--OUTPUT_FILE:":
                out=outputName(value)
        return seq,conA
except getopt.GetoptError,err:
       print str(err)
       print "Please use the correct arguments, for usage type --help"

def inputFile(value):
try:
    fh = open(value,'r')
except IOError:
    print "The file %s does not exist \n" % value
else:
    ToSeperate= (x[1] for x in groupby(fh, lambda line: line[0] == ">"))
    for header in ToSeperate:
        header = header.next()[1:].strip()
        Sequence = "".join(s.strip() for s in ToSeperate.next())
        return Sequence

 def MutationFile(value):
 try:
    fh=open(value,'r')
    content=fh.read()
    Rmcontent=str(content.rstrip())
 except IOError:
    print "The file %s does not exist \n" % MutFile
 else:
    con=list(Rmcontent)
    return con

def Mutation(SEQUENCES,conA):
 R=len(conA)
 if R>1:
    out=[]  
    SecondNum=1
    ThirdChar=2
    for index in range(len(conA)):
        MR=conA[index]
        if index==SecondNum:
            SN=MR
            SecondNum=SecondNum+4
        if index==ThirdChar:
            TC=MR
            ThirdChar=ThirdChar+4

            SecNum=int(SN.rstrip())
            MutateResidue=str(TC.rstrip())
            for index in range(len(SEQUENCES)):
                if index==SecNum-1:
                    NonMutate=SEQUENCES[index]
                    AfterMutate=NonMutate.replace(NonMutate,MutateResidue)
                    new=SEQUENCES[ :index]+AfterMutate+SEQUENCES[index+1: ]
                    MutatedInformation= ['>',NonMutate,index+1,MutateResidue,'\n',new]
                    values2 = ''.join(str(i)for i in MutatedInformation)

if __name__ == "__main__":          
seq,conA=main(sys.argv[1:])
Mutation(seq,conA)
```

This is my part of program where I replaced R,W,G of (2,4,6) to E,C,E then stored those replaced letter into variable called R which contain three lines like this:-

```
PrACCEL
PEAwCEL
PEACCgL
```

Now, I want to make 2 and 3 combination out of these three single mutations.
It would be like Comb of two mutations in one line and three mutation in one line.

sample and expected output will be like this:

```
2C
   PrAwCEL 
   PrACCgL 
   PEAwCgL 
3C
   PrAwCgL
```

Algorithm

his is part of my code so i will explain my algorithm

1.I read the mutation file which has three characters for eg (E2R) where (E)is amino acid letter which is (2) position of input sequence PEACCEL and third letter (R) is E2 going to be R.

2.So first I extracted positions and third variable from user mutation file and stored those into variables SecNum and MutateResidue(thirdchar).

3.then,I used for loop to read a sequence(PEACCEL) by index then whichever index match to SecNUm(E2,4,6) i replaced those sequence with those with Mutate Residue which is third character in mutation file (2R,4W,6G)

4.then finally I joined mutated residue index with other residue by this line:(new=SEQUENCES[:index]+AfterMutate+SEQUENCES[index+1: ]

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is part of my code so i will explain my algorithm 1.  I read the mutation file which has three characters for eg (E2R) where (E)is amino acid letter which is (2) position of input sequence PEACCEL and third letter (R) is E2 going to be R.So first I extracted positions and third variable from user mutation file and stored those into variables SecNum and MutateResidue(thirdchar). then,I used for loop to read a sequence(PEACCEL) by index then whichever index match to SecNUm(E2,4,6) i replaced those sequence with those with Mutate Residue which is third character in mutation file (2R,4W,6G)

Comment: then finally I joined mutated residue index with other residue by this line:(new=SEQUENCES[ :index]+AfterMutate+SEQUENCES[index+1: ]

Comment: Sorry dear friend sundar nataraj Сундар Since I was editing i couldnt able to see your reply last time. and this is to inform you that my main aim is to make 2,3 combination out of single mutation file which has three lines

Comment: please accept question and my contact is iamsundar04@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations,chain
from collections import Counter


def Mutation(SEQUENCES,conA):
    
    #mutations=map(lambda x:x.strip(),open('a.txt','r').readlines())
    
    mutation_combinations= chain.from_iterable([list(combinations(conA,i))for i in range(1,4)])
    #[('E2R',), ('C4W',), ('E6G',), ('E2R', 'C4W'), ('E2R', 'E6G'), ('C4W', 'E6G'), ('E2R', 'C4W', 'E6G')]
    
    for i in mutation_combinations:
        print "combination :"+'_'.join(i)
        c=Counter({})
        temp_string=SEQUENCES
        for j in i:
            c[j[1]]=j[2].lower()
        for index,letter in c.items():
            temp_string=temp_string[:int(index)-1]+letter+temp_string[int(index):]
        print temp_string
```

## output

```
combination :E2R
PrACCEL
combination :C4W
PEAwCEL
combination :E6G
PEACCgL
combination :E2R_C4W
PrAwCEL
combination :E2R_E6G
PrACCgL
combination :C4W_E6G
PEAwCgL
combination :E2R_C4W_E6G
PrAwCgL
```

Algorithm i followed:

1. read the mutation sequences like E2R.... from a file using `mutations=map(lambda x:x.strip(),open('a.txt','r').readlines())`
2. made the combinations of the mutations `mutation_combinations= chain.from_iterable([list(combinations(mutations,i))for i in range(1,4)])` if you have `4` mutations you want all four change the `range value to 5`
3. so for each combination i replaced them with specified character

   ```
   for j in i:
       c[j[1]]=j[2].lower()
   ```

i used above counter to keep track of which character to be replaced during mutation combination

Comment: I m getting combination like this:combination :E
combination :2
combination :R
combination :
combination :C
combination :4
combination :W
combination :
combination :E
combination :6
I thing this is because we need to change this conA list to string right ?

Comment: @user3805057 yes conA should be like ['E2R', 'C4W', 'E6G']

Comment: I changed some ot these modification                             str = ''.join(conA)--->
  mut= str.split("\n")---> mutation_combinations=chain.from_iterable([list(combinations(mut,i))-->for i in range(1,4)])-->
  for i in mutation_combinations:-->
  print ">"+'_'.join(i)  and am getting results like this             >E2R
>C4W
>E6G
>E2R_C4W
>E2R_E6G
>C4W_E6G
>E2R_C4W_E6G

Comment: @user3805057 can you just print conA value which your getting and sequence value  in your method

Comment: final output am getting like this:>E2R
PrACCEL
>C4W
PEAwCEL
>E6G
PEACCgL
>E2R_C4W
PrACCEL
PrACCEL
PrAwCEL
>E2R_E6G
PrACCEL
PrACCEL
PrACCgL
>C4W_E6G
PEAwCEL
PEAwCEL
PEAwCgL
>E2R_C4W_E6G
PrACCEL
PrACCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCgL                                                             but i want like this                                             >E2R
PrACCEL
>C4W
PEAwCEL
>E6G
PEACCgL

>E2R_C4W
PrAwCEL

>E2R_E6G
PrACCgL

>C4W_E6G
PEAwCgL

>E2R_C4W_E6G
PrAwCgL

Comment: @user3805057 i am totally confused:(.

Comment: Almost i got answer which i expected but for two and three combinations i need only last line not the previous lines for eg:- in this >E2R_C4W_E6G
PrACCEL
PrACCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCEL
PrAwCgL   I WANT TO PRINT ONLY THIS LINE >E2R_C4W_E6G PrAwCgL

Comment: @user3805057 oh you dont want single mutation right ? you want only 2c and 3c

Comment: @user3805057 my freind you have changed the intendation please place the temp_string in the line of last for not in the for

Comment: >E2R 
PRACCEL 
>C4W 
PEAWCEL 
>E6G 
PEACCGL 
>E2R_C4W 
PRAWCEL 
>E2R_E6G 
PRACCGL 
>C4W_E6G 
PEAWCGL 
>E2R_C4W_E6G 
PRAWCGL   like this i want

Comment: @user3805057 yes you will get like that only you have placed print temp_string inside loop i think keep it out of for loop see my code clearly

Comment: I dont want to print single mutations inside 2C and 3C

Comment: Is it possible to build a same logic in argparse instead of getopt. which should work same like this: take arguments from user, passing the values to sub function and again returning sub function values to main function. I want to do this because for some arguments i want to give default values which is not possible in getopt

Comment: Is it possible to build a same logic in argparse instead of getopt. which should work same like this: take arguments from user, passing the values to sub function and again returning sub function values to main function. I want to do this because for some arguments i want to give default values which is not possible in getopt